# Individually indent wrapped lines of lines broken with \\

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, wrap, hangindent

I have long lines like this:

```latex
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist, \\
Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word, \\
Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, \\
```

Which render as:

> Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of
> John the Baptist,
>
> Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation
> of the Divine Word,
>
> Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to
> his home again,

But I want:

> Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of
>      John the Baptist,
>
> Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation
>      of the Divine Word,
>
> Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to
>      his home again,

How do I indent what is wrapped?

Is there a way of doing with with a `\renewcommand{\\}{…}`?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want such text separated from the context by some vertical space and with wider margins.

In this realization, the standard width is 75% of the column width, but you can specify a different one with an optional argument. I use this feature to show that when the width is the same as the column width, the lines fit exactly in the text box.

Instead of `\\` I suggest to use blank lines, but it's up to you to choose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{hymn}[1][0.75\columnwidth]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{-\hymnindent}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\dimeval{(\columnwidth-#1)/2+\hymnindent}}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\dimeval{\leftskip-\hymnindent}}%
  \let\\=\par
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\newlength{\hymnindent}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\hymnindent}{\parindent}% or whatever you prefer
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{hymn}
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,\\
Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,\\
Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, and did something else which I write here just to show what happens with a long line
\end{hymn}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{hymn}[\columnwidth]
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,

Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,

Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, and did something else which I write here just to show what happens with a long line
\end{hymn}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to have the headlines flush left.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{hymn}[1][0.75\columnwidth]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{-\hymnindent}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\hymnindent}
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\dimeval{\columnwidth+\hymnindent-#1}}%
  \let\\=\par
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\newlength{\hymnindent}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\hymnindent}{\parindent}% or whatever you prefer
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{hymn}
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,\\
Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,\\
Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, and did something else which I write here just to show what happens with a long line
\end{hymn}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{hymn}[\columnwidth]
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,

Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,

Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, and did something else which I write here just to show what happens with a long line
\end{hymn}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `parskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{hymn}[1][0.75\columnwidth]
 {%
  \par
  \addvspace{\parskip}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{-\hymnindent}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\hymnindent}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{\dimeval{\columnwidth+\hymnindent-#1}}%
  \let\\=\par
 }
 {\par}

\newlength{\hymnindent}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\hymnindent}{2em}% or whatever you prefer
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{hymn}
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,\\
Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,\\
Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, and did something else which I write here just to show what happens with a long line
\end{hymn}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{hymn}[\columnwidth]
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,

Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,

Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, and did something else which I write here just to show what happens with a long line
\end{hymn}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neither of your example commands produce a hanging indent for me  in the `book` class.

Comment: There's no way to do what I'm asking with `\renewcommand{\\}{…}`?

Comment: @geremia My crystal ball tells me you’re using `parskip`

Comment: @Geremia `\setlength{\hymnindent}{2em}` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: That will get it to work with `parskip`?

Comment: @Geremia Of course. The `2em` or the length you prefer should take the place of `\parindent` in the `\setlength` declaration.

Comment: How do I change it so it doesn't have extra vertical space between lines?

Comment: @Geremia Look at the added version.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the vertical space issue; `hymn` environments are now single-spaced. But I still get that the first line in the `hymn` environment immediately following a `\subsection{}` is indented.

Comment: @Geremia I cannot read minds. Please ask a new question with all the needed details.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering why you didn't post minimal code?

Here is one approach, taking into account the default behavior; as you can see, there's little more to do unless we know at least your pages geometry etc.:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{As posted}
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist, \\
Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word, \\
Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again, \\

\section{Some trials}
Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of

John the Baptist, \\
Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation

of the Divine Word, \\
Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to

his home again, \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't want to do the breaking manually.

Comment: As you stated, and as your code shows ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Although note quite its intended use, perhaps the `scripture` package would suit you. There's plenty of options to adjust the indents and spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scripture}
\scripturesetup{
  poetry/indent=0pt,
  poetry/bigindent=2em,
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
  \begin{scripture}
    \begin{poetry}
      Saint Gabriel, who didst foretell to Zachary the birth and ministry of John the Baptist,
      Saint Gabriel, who didst announce to Blessed Mary the Incarnation of the Divine Word,
      Saint Raphael, who didst lead Tobias safely through his journey to his home again,
    \end{poetry}
  \end{scripture}
\end{quote}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]